# Tips for optimizing Python filtering program

Tags: python, optimization

I have been working on a very simple program, with the gist of it shown below:

```
    post = open(INPUTFILE1, "rb")
    for line in post:
        cut = line.split(',')
        pre = open(INPUTFILE2, "rb")
        for otherline in pre:
            cuttwo = otherline.split(',')
            if cut[1] == cuttwo[1] and cut[3] == cuttwo[3] and cut[9] == cuttwo[9]:
                OUTPUTFILE.write(otherline)
                break
    post.close()
    pre.close()
    OUTPUTFILE.close()
```

Effectively what this does is take two csv files as inputs (a "pre" and a "post").  It looks at the first line in the "post" data and attempts to find a line in the "pre" data that matches on columns 2, 4, and 10.  If there is a match, it writes the "pre" data to a new file.

It works just fine, but it takes forever.  Although my "post" data may have only a few hundred (up to maybe a thousand) rows, my "pre" may have as many as 15 million.  As a result, it may take somewhere on the order of 10 hours to finish.

I am fairly new to Python, so I have yet to learn much in the way of optimization techniques.  Does anyone have any pointers as to what I could try?  Obviously I understand that the logjam is occurring when I search the entirety of the "pre" data for a match.  Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: This is more a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than SO.

Answer (score 4):

If you've only got a few hundred rows that are potentials, then use something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
key = itemgetter(1, 3, 9)
with open('smallfile') as fin:
    valid = set(key(line.split(',')) for line in fin)

with open('largerfile') as fin:
    lines = (line.split(',') for line in fin)
    for line in lines:
        if key(line) in valid:
            # do something....
```

This saves unnecessary iteration and makes the most of a Python builtin for efficient lookup.

If you want to use the entire lines of the small file in the output if there is a match, then use a dictionary rather than a set:

```
from operator import itemgetter
key = itemgetter(1, 3, 9)
with open('smallfile') as fin:
    valid = dict((key(line.split(',')), line) for line in fin)
```

And then your processing loop would be something like:

```
with open('largerfile') as fin:
    lines = (line.split(',') for line in fin)
    for line in lines:
        otherline = valid.get(key(line), None)
        if otherline is not None:
            # do something....
```

Comment: +1. Don't repeatedly process the file, do it the once and cache the results. @JonClements - I've added in an example of using a dictionary so the entire line can be retrieved if later needed. Hope thats OK with you.